# Scheduled Tasks in Java - which tool to use

Tags: java, timer, scheduler

I have the following goal:
I have a multiplayer game where are thousands of characters with unique abilities. These abilities switch on or switch off at particular times - ie. it might switch on at 3pm. and it might switch off at 3.05 pm. I was thinking to implement it as a global counter with events attached to it so that when the time comes, the event gets triggered, and the ability is switched on. How can I achieve that in Java? If I spawn too many threads, it might take down the system because there are too many characters. Which tool (or maybe other method) should I use?

Comment: Have you tried `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` ?

Comment: Not really. But I am asking for an advice to choose sth which is the best choice.

Comment: you could create events (timer tasks or ScheduledFutures) for each character, but sometimes it may be better to create events based on the event time and then iterate over the characters, and execute the event if needed. E.g. if you have 1.000.000 characters, you probably don't want five events per character in your event queue, where each event only modifies a flag inside the character object. Even if you use a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with 16 Threads on a hardware with 16 native thread, you will miss most of the event times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), we are using it on projects from small to enterprise-large apps.